# Modify a function without directly editing it

Tags: php

I am looking to modify a function inside a Wordpress plugin, where I am switching to the primary site in a multisite installation to load images. The plugin is regularly maintained, and therefore I do not want to modify the code so that I am able to easily update it.

Is there anyway to 'hook' into the function so that I can modify it this way? I have shown what I am trying to achieve below, where I have had to manually add `switch_to_blog(1)` and `restore_current_blog()`.

```
function get_value($post_id, $field)
{
    $value = parent::get_value($post_id, $field);

    switch_to_blog(1);

    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => null,
        'post__in' => $value,
    ));

    $ordered_attachments = array();
    foreach( $attachments as $attachment)
    {
        $ordered_attachments[ $attachment->ID ] = array(
            'id' => $attachment->ID,
            'alt' => get_post_meta($attachment->ID, 
                        '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true),
            'title' => $attachment->post_title,
        );
    }

    restore_current_blog();

    return $ordered_attachments;
}
```

Comment: If only you could extend one of the plugin's classes... <snicker />

Comment: you might want to post this on the WordPress stackexchange: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @dnagirl I've posted it here as I think it's more of a general question regarding functions than a WP problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask the original author(s) to split the function:

```
function get_ordered_attachments_by_field($post_id, $field)
{
    $value = parent::get_value($post_id, $field);

    return get_ordered_attachments($value);
}

function get_ordered_attachments($value)
{
    $attachments = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => null,
        'post__in' => $value,
    ));

    $ordered_attachments = array();
    foreach ($attachments as $attachment)
    {
        $ordered_attachments[ $attachment->ID ] = array(
            'id' => $attachment->ID,
            'alt' => get_post_meta($attachment->ID, 
                        '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true),
            'title' => $attachment->post_title,
        );
    }

    return $ordered_attachments;
}
```

You can then more easily interact with the functionality you need, e.g.

```
    $value = $object->get_value($post_id, $field)
    switch_to_blog(1);
    $attachments = $object->get_ordered_attachments($value);
    restore_current_blog();
```

And the job is done. The benefit for the project is that they have reduced (at least a little bit) the lines of code in the attachment function and made it more concrete what the function does by it's name. No idea what that object is, if it's a plugin this looks anyway like a place to store functions in, so create more and more functions, but smaller ones.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can only "hook" into a function if the developers had code a "do_action" line. If this is not the case, you can create a copy of the function and call your copy instead of the original, but if the function is called inside the plugin, you can do nothing, only modify the plugin (as you sayed this is not a good idea)

Comment: This wouldn't really be ideal as it would mean the plugin wouldn't be able to update.

Answer (score 1):

You can override particular plugin functions by putting replacement functions in a file stored in `wp-contents/mu-plugins`

You should check to make sure that the original function is inside an `if()` block that checks if it already exists.  If it's not, then this method won't work.

Comment: It's not in an `if` block so unfortunately this would not work.